# Using Linq to read from multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm sure someone else has asked this but I searched on what I could think of to find the solution.

I've got the following data models to match tables in my SQL db:

```
public class ProfileDetailModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public StyleList[] styleList { get; set; }
    public FabricList[] fabricList { get; set; }

}

public class StyleList
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class FabricList
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string fabricName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the current query code:

```
        var query = (from t in db.tblProfiles
                     select new ProfileDetailModel()
                     {
                         id = t.id,
                         name = t.name
                     });

        var querylist = await query.ToListAsync();
```

(prototyped linq queries below for style and fabric)

```
        var styleQuery = (from t in db.tblStyles
                     select new styleList()
                     {
                         id = t.id,
                         name = t.name
                     });

        var fabricQuery = (from t in db.tblFabrics
                           select new fabricList()
                           {
                               id = t.id,
                               name = t.name
                           });

        if (queryList.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = queryList[0];
            item.styleList = styleQuery;
            item.fabricList = fabricQuery;
        }
```

I'll have one profileDetailModel with multiple items in styleList and in fabricList.  EG.

ProfileDetailModel

Data: Pants

- styleList: Bell Bottom, Straight Leg, Boot fit
- fabricList: jean-blue, jean-black, plaid

All three above models are tables in my db.  I could issue 3 separate queries to read the data then assemble after the fact.  But is there a way I can do a linq query to include the two arrays in the main query in one shot?

Comment: If I do a join, the ProfileDetailModel will list for each item in StyleList and Fabric List so I'll have duplicates.

There is one ProfileDetailModel for many of styleList and fabricList.  I'll modify the question to include that

Comment: So linq has directly nothing to do with data access...  Is this [tag:entity-framework] or [tag:linq2sql]?

Comment: entity framework on the azure platform

Comment: I just prototyped what I would normally do for the other two queries above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var newQuery = (from p in db.tblProfiles
                    select p)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => new ProfileDetailModel()
                    {
                        id = x.id,
                        name = x.name,
                        styleList = styleQuery,
                        fabricList = fabricQuery
                    });
```

Comment: @DaBlue looks fine , please try and post result

Comment: what is meant by styleQuery and fabricQuery?  do I create another query like the profileDetailModel query (var query)?

Comment: When you had the line [Load other tables here], I assumed that you meant to initialize them as well, since I'm not sure where that data is coming from.  I actualy put the whole thing in LinqPad to test.

Comment: StyleList[] styleQuery = new StyleList[] { new StyleList() { id = "2", name = "TestStyle" } };
 FabricList[] fabricQuery = new FabricList[] { new FabricList() { id = "3", fabricName = "TestFabricList" } };

Comment: Just for testing.  Fill in your own values.

Comment: That's what I would have done in the past...  However, I'm doing async right now so I'm trying to minimize query times for the mobile app I'm working on.

Comment: Just saw you edit. Are the id fields in StyleList and FabricList primary keys or foreign keys from ProfileDataModel?  How do they link (or are they always just part of the object)?

Comment: You can add the await back in. I just left it off of mine.

Comment: they are PKs.  I do have a fk in the DB though.  The other two queries are just prototypes because no matter what I was trying to do with the syntax on the linq query, I couldn't figure out if it was possible.  I want to keep the query count down if possible (Azure keeps track of that) so doing one query vs three would be most beneficial.

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for...  There should be an array in the model containing the fabric.  The above example does not do that.  What I want returned is the profileDetailModel as above.  Note the array in the model.

Comment: It seems like you need a foreign key in StyleList and FabricList to filter on the style and fabric for that particular ProfileDetail (e.g. like ProfileDetailID).  That way you can have all of the fabrics you have in the fabric class and just show the ones for pants when you need it.  If that is what you want your query will have some joins but I can show that to you.  I'm not sure from what you have provided how you will know which fabrics/styles to use.